# blackjack game: for loops 'not in' vs 'in'

Tags: python, for-loop

I have run into some trouble using for loops while making a blackjack game simulation. The function `new_game` simulates four cards being dealt, while `new_card` ensures no card is repeated in a game. I created two variations of the function `new game` and was wondering how they differ.

In Version 1, there were situations where the function only returned 3 cards, while Version 2 seems to work as expected.

Version 1:

```
def new_game():
game=[];
for x in range(4):
    n=new_card();
    if n not in game:
        game+=[n];
    else:
        new_game();
    print(game);
return game
```

Version 2:

```
def new_game():
game=[];
for x in range(4):
    n=new_card();
    if n in game:
        new_game();
        print(game);
    else:
        game+=[n];
return game
```

Comment: for your reference here is the function `new_card`. 

`def new_card():
 s=['s','c','d','h'];
 n=list(range(1,14));
 return [random.choice(s),random.choice(n)];
`

Comment: Don't understand why `new_game()` is getting called recursively when `new_card()` couldn't produce an unique card. I think the code should be calling `new_card()` until a unique one is generated for the loop iteration. What do you think?

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing that out. I meant to say `new_game` checks for repeated cards. When a repeated card is found, the function starts over. It seems like `new_game()` works, but do you think calling `new_card()` would be more efficient?

Comment: Yes, consider if you have 3  cards in the list and the fourth you obtain is already present in the list, then it would be better to just search for a new card rather than starting all over again.

Comment: It's unrelated to the issue you're having, but I thought I'd note that semicolons are not required at the end of Python statements. They're allowed, mostly because you occasionally want to put multiple simple statements on one line (often for a one-liner script run from the command line with `python -c`), but it's not good style to use them when you don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `new_game` is not the best way to solve this project. You can try multiple ways , one of which I am showing. Rather than a constant for loop try to check the length of list until it is of desired length.

```
def new_game():
    game=[];
    while len(game)!=4:
        n = new_card()
        while(n in game):
            n = new_card()
        else:
            game.append(n)
    return game

print new_game()
```

I am not sure if this is a good design but still it works and you may modify it.

**EDIT**

Thanks to  Blckknght for suggesting this.

```
def new_game():
    game=[]
    while len(game)!=4:
        n = new_card()
        if n not in game:
            game.append(n)
    return game

print new_game()
```

Comment: I think you want `n = new_card()` in the inner loop. Otherwise you'll run forever if the first pick is a duplicate, as `n` doesn't change.

Comment: I don't get you. How can the first pick be a duplicate, the `game` list is empty initially.  Although I have revised. Please see if you think it's correct.Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: By "first pick" I meant the `n = new_card()` line in the outer `while` loop (in contrast with a pick in the inner loop). It would only happen on one of the later passes of the outer loop. Though, actually, since you've changed the Questioner's `for` outer loop into a `while`, you don't actually need an inner loop at all. You could just have the one loop and do `if n not in game: game.append(n)` with no `else` block.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. Pretty stupid of me to use two `while` loops